# Unable to run example of PhoneGap for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I tried to follow this instruction:
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494774/Getting-started-with-Android-PhoneGap-in-Eclipse

I can run the example but when I clicked on the "Beep" button or anything button, it has error in "adb logcat" like this and the app crashed:

```
D/dalvikvm(  387): GC_EXPLICIT freed 115K, 52% free 2656K/5447K, external 2075K/
2792K, paused 4856ms  

I/BootReceiver(   68): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_07 to DropBox (SYSTEM_
TOMBSTONE)  

I/DEBUG   (   30): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!  

D/Zygote  (   32): Process 425 terminated by signal (11)  

I/ActivityManager(   68): Process com.PhoneGap3 (pid 425) has died.  

I/WindowManager(   68): WIN DEATH: Window{406acdf0 com.PhoneGap3/com.PhoneGap3.P
honeGap3 paused=false}  

I/InputDispatcher(   68): Dropping event because there is no touched window or f
ocused application.  

I/DEBUG   (  440): debuggerd: Nov 24 2010 13:31:11  

D/dalvikvm(   68): GC_CONCURRENT freed 957K, 48% free 4497K/8583K, external 2062
K/2576K, paused 46ms+19ms  

D/dalvikvm(   68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 373K, 46% free 4635K/8583K, external 2062
K/2576K, paused 340ms  

I/dalvikvm-heap(   68): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.291MB for 196628-byte allocat
ion  

D/dalvikvm(   68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 46% free 4826K/8839K, external 2062K
/2576K, paused 231ms  

W/InputManagerService(   68): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notif
ication to pid 425 uid 10040
```

Can someone help please? Thanks.

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case something went wrong along the project creation phase, check out http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap-Eclipse-PlugIn-for-Android  The plugin described will configure and build the example automatically and should be an easier startup experience.

Comment: I followed that and ran the sample. When I clicked "Beep, it still crashed. Can you help? This is the log https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1uolIYeQ6f1RSvKwt4I1mkc626umkJXnvLe1CkrVH8Ws

Comment: Hm, I can't make much sense of the log.  What did you enter in the Eclipse Project Creation dialogs?  See http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap-Eclipse-PlugIn-for-Android as a reference.

Comment: I entered exactly like the link you gave me. It crashed when I clicked anything. Look at last few lines in the log --> "Process 406 terminated by signal ..."

Comment: Hmm, my logs are basically the same up until 01-14 08:24:18.831: INFO/ActivityManager(117): Displayed activity com.Sample/.myActivity: 223 ms (total 223 ms).   What is your device and OS version?  Also, perhaps if you focus the phonegap mailing list on the specific part of the log between the display and the webkit stack trace, someone might have more ideas.

Comment: I use Windows 7, Android 2.3 and latest Phonegap at Github. Not sure what you mean regarding to the "phonegap mailing list"?

Comment: Are you running on a 2.3 device?  The 2.3 emulator doesn't work with the emulator. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987 In any case you should try Android 2.2.  I mean just posting the few key lines of the log at http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap

Comment: PaulB: I'm having a similar problem with the PhoneGap Android/Sample project. This is with PG 0.9.3, with the latest Android SDK (including the Honeycomb Preview). The project builds fine, and the classes.dex shows that the com.phonegap.Sample.Sample class is in classes.dex, but the app Force-Closes on startup, with adb reporting that the error is a ClassNotFoundException, failing to find com.phonegap.Sample.Sample.

Any ideas?

Comment: @TedN Not sure. I typically use the Eclipse method described at http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap-Eclipse-PlugIn-for-Android which provides a wizard to create the sample.